# How can I download files to my trigger.io app?

Tags: trigger.io

How can I download files to my trigger.io app? My app shows offline data, but I need the way how my app can download and store localy fresh data from server. Data are one js fole with array of items and some images, each one for each product item from array. For Phonegap there is something like this http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/51679022/Download+File+From+Internet, is there anything for trigger.io?

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cache the file(s) locally - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/features/cache.html

And/or you can utilize user preferences - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/prefs.html

Also, check this out -  http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/file.html

```
cacheURL
```